# How to setup flexible routing between 2 LAN's at home

Tags: router, routing, adsl

I have two separate internet connctions at home, one Huawei B593 4G router and one Netgear ADSL router.

Normally I use the 4G connection (with the ADSL as a backup when I hit the 80GB data limit per month) and the rest of the family is using the ADSL connection (with no data limit).

Both the Huawei and the Netgear routers have Wifi access, and today I have a switch which connects the Huawei with the Netgear.

The Huawei network address range is 192.168.2.X and the Netgear is 192.168.0.X

Now when I want to switch from 4G to ADSL I must manually switch address on a number of PC's from 192.168.2.X to 192.168.0.X (and also of course change default route etc)

I was thinking instead that I should connect the networks with a cheap router. Alternatively a software router on one of my Linux boxes ( I have Windows, OSX and Linux). I want to be able to switch internet line at will.

Which solution should I choose, and is there a simple/quick way I could route the traffic to the Netgear network and then back to the 4G net whenever I want?

If possible, I would also want to route some traffic (P2P, Web-TV etc) to the ADSL while some traffic (gaming mostly) to the quick 4G net. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that this is the best solution (aside from spending hours on building and configuring my own).

http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/ps11995/

Its a cheap(ish) Cisco router with 4 ethernet ports. I have a somewhat dated experience of IOS (the router operating system) but I hope this one can solve my basic problems of routing. However I don't know how I shall be able to quickly switch between subnets.

Answer (score 0):

While the last question I would have a problem answering (Routing some traffic but not others), you will most likely need software routers (or one where you can fully manage the routing table). You will basically need to forward all packets from the routers whose connection you don't want to go through to the other router (gateway). I'm sure you could condense this into one machine with pFsense.

Comment: Yes I was thinking along that path myself. Was wondering however whether there existed some cheap hardware solution, like from D-link or Netgear. Deosnt anyone use ethernet routers anymore? All I can find are switches and (non-manageble) Wifi routers. Seems strange that I would have to dedicate a computer with software router for such a relatively simple task?

Comment: I don't personally know but I do know you do start venturing out into the enterprise world when you start needing certain features.